# Header of brush setting is missing in the grease pencil in Blender

Tags: grease-pencil, draw-mode

[image]

[image]

The header of brush setting (Fig.2) is missing in the grease pencil in Blender that it is not able to adjust the setting now.(Fig.1) I tried right clicked the menu but the [show header] button is not able to select. Help!!

Comment: right-click on any tool from the top bar then Header > Show Tool Settings

Comment: The [Header] option is grey in colour and is not able to select.

Comment: `Header` should be a pop-up/drop-down menu with more options inside it. Dunno why it's not coming up in your case, sorry

Comment: Thanks for trying to provides help. This is a blend file downloaded from Blender Cloud that the header of brush is so weird to be disappeared...